# How to get a margin on a floated element?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-float, margin

I'm trying to introduce a generic solution where I will attach an icon left of a random html element. This item will have a certain width and gets positioned absolutely next to the other element. To avoid the icon from overlapping the element beside of the element, I decided to increase the margin of that element by the width of the icon. This works like a charm - except when there's a floated element. The margin just ignores the floated's elements presence.

Is there a solution to this without adding wrapper divs etc? this approach should be as generic as possible.

If there is one with javascript, i'd be fine with that. E.g. checking for css attributes like floated would be fine - but I don't know the solution in the first place.

Having this problem for example:

[a table next to a floated element requires a margin](http://jsbin.com/alaguc/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

make your span "display:block" and either give it a width or increase the margin of your table